# Best way to find the top most left coordinate point in set of Cartesian coordinates?

Tags: coordinates

I have a set of cartesian coordinates. What is the best way to find the **top most left** coordinate?
My approach is to find max Y and then corresponding lowest X coordinate. (Since there could be multiple points with same Ymax). This works fine but wonders if there are other cute methods?

Comment: Linear search if the coordinates are not ordered in some way.

Answer (score 0):

If your x and y coordinates are not sorted, then you have to check all the input coordinates - at first your y values (for **topmost**, the higher the better) and then all corresponding x values for such y, but now you look for minimal x.